# Sencha Touch - Scroll Delay on First Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I have been searching around and it looks like this question has been asked quite a few times in various places with no answers or responses. That means that I can't be the only one experiencing this.

There is always a delay in the scrolling when you try to scroll a list or panel for the first time. After the first time you scroll a list or panel, there is no longer any delay. Is there a way I can simulate this "first touch" in an effort to remove the delay when attempting to scroll a list or panel for the first time?

I've been looking through the ScrollView and Scroller code and have not been able to find a point where anything heavy or expensive is happening on a first touch.

Any help or direction on how to remedy this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: did u figure out the issue ? as m facing the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open the Chrome/Safari developer tools and start profiling("Profiles" tab) to see if there is any JavaScript code that is performing badly and causing the hang.
If it's not code that hangs, it might be a web browser issue (e.g. image cache allocation), for example due to the first time that things dynamically change in your web app.
It's also important to try and compare platforms and see if they have the same issue.

It's also often helpful if you specify the Sencha version (I assume 1.x?) and the platform(s) you've had the issue with. iOS/Android/PC can often react quite differently.